# How to convert a string into a DOM element for use with the canvas element?

Tags: javascript, string, dom, canvas, element

HTML:

```
<img src="person.png" id="person"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var object0 = document.getElementById("person");
var i = 0;

context.drawImage(object0, object0X, object0Y);// this works

context.drawImage("object" + i, object0X, object0Y);// this doesn't
```

Error message:

```
Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]
```

I read somewhere that the reason I get the error is that it has to be a DOM element, not a string. Well, I need to run a for loop so I can affect several objects on screen and therefore need to do some concatenation. Is there something similar to parseInt() I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing a variable using a string literal will result in an error because it will evaluate to a string literal.

```
var Object0 = document.getElementById('person'); // typeof 'object'
console.log(typeof ('Object' + i)); // This will output 'string' to the console
```

You could instead create an object whose properties hold references to DOM elements.

```
var images = {
    Object0: document.getElementById('person')
    // and so forth...
};
```

This is extremely useful because you can reference each property using bracket notation. Now, you can loop through the properties with a for loop and access the values; like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    context.drawImage(images['Object' + i], Object0X, Object0Y); // This works
    console.log(typeof images['Object' + i]); // This will output 'object' to the console
}
```

Comment: +1 for being exactly correct. Note that in this case there may be no need to use an object with named properties instead of just an array: `var images = []; images[0] = document.querySelector('#person'); for (...){ ctx.drawImage(images[i], ...); }`

Comment: @Phrogz Very true; the simplest solution sometimes escapes me.

Comment: FWIW, whenever someone is trying to dynamically look up local variables the suggestion to store them as named entries in an object _is_ the default first answer, so it's totally understandable (and good to have there in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

`context.drawImage(document.getElementById("object" + i), object0X, object0Y);`

Which would require that you have image elements with the ids `object0`, `object1`, `object2`...

Comment: -1 for not seeing that the OP already had an explicit ID that was not "object0".

Comment: I did see that. I assumed he had other image objects as well and wanted to get those but didn't know how to simply concatenate a string and use it in getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference JS variables via strings. The error originates from passing a string to the drawImage function, not a reference to the image. Just pass the variable to the function, and it works.

Comment: Correct, but this answer doesn't actually help the OP who was clearly trying to dynamically construct the reference.

Comment: I had the impression that this is a PHP-like take on variable passing. But at least I'm glad nobody suggested using `eval` so far…